# How to groupby multiple columns and create a new column in Python based on thresholds

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have  dataframe like below

**Input**

```
Invoice No  Date    Text            Vendor    Days
1000001     1/1/2020    Rent Payment    A   0
1000003     2/1/2020    Rent Payment    A   1
1000005     4/1/2020    Rent Payment    A   2
1000007     6/1/2020    Water payment   A   2
1000008     9/2/2020    Rep Payment     A   34
1000010     9/2/2020    Car Payment     A   0
1000011     10/2/2020   Car Payment     A   1
1000012     15/2/2020   Car Payment     A   5
1000013     16/2/2020   Car Payment     A   1
1000015     17/2/2020   Car Payment     A   1
1000002     1/1/2020    Rent Payment    B   -47
1000004     4/1/2020    Con Payment     B   3
1000006     6/1/2020    Con Payment     B   2
1000009     9/2/2020    Water payment   B   34
1000014    17/2/2020    Test Payment    B   8
1000016    19/2/2020    Test Payment    B   2
```

**Condition**

How write python condition which check the description,vendor name and days column and if the description,vendor name is the same and the no of days is <=2 then the rows should be grouped together under common group name say (G1) all the other rows can be assigned a unique group name.All grouped rows should have unique group name  as shown in the output

**Expected Output**

```
Invoice No  Date        Text          Vendor   Days    Group
1000001     1/1/2020    Rent Payment    A       0        G1
1000003     2/1/2020    Rent Payment    A       1        G1
1000005     4/1/2020    Rent Payment    A       2        G1
1000007     6/1/2020    Water payment   A       2        G2
1000008     9/2/2020    Rep Payment     A       34       G3
1000010     9/2/2020    Car Payment     A       0        G4
1000011    10/2/2020    Car Payment     A       1        G4
1000012    15/2/2020    Car Payment     A       5        G5
1000013    16/2/2020    Car Payment     A       1        G5
1000015    17/2/2020    Car Payment     A       1        G5
1000002    1/1/2020     Rent Payment    B      -47       G6
1000004    4/1/2020     Con Payment     B       3        G7
1000006    6/1/2020     Con Payment     B       2        G7
1000009    9/2/2020     Water payment   B      34        G8
1000014    17/2/2020    Test Payment    B       8        G9
1000016    19/2/2020    Test Payment    B       2        G9
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `groupby` on three items: `'Text'`, `'Vendor'`, and a boolean representation of whether `'Days'` changes by more than `2` within the groups defined by `['Text', 'Vendor']` alone.

After that, you need to name the unique groups.  I provide two methods below.

#### `ngroup`

```
f = lambda x: x.diff().fillna(0).gt(2).cumsum()
d = df.groupby(['Text', 'Vendor']).Days.transform(f)
g = df.groupby(['Text', 'Vendor', d], sort=False).ngroup()
df.assign(Group=g.add(1).astype(str).radd('G'))

    Invoice No       Date           Text Vendor  Days Group
0      1000001   1/1/2020   Rent Payment      A     0    G1
1      1000003   2/1/2020   Rent Payment      A     1    G1
2      1000005   4/1/2020   Rent Payment      A     2    G1
3      1000007   6/1/2020  Water payment      A     2    G2
4      1000008   9/2/2020    Rep Payment      A    34    G3
5      1000010   9/2/2020    Car Payment      A     0    G4
6      1000011  10/2/2020    Car Payment      A     1    G4
7      1000012  15/2/2020    Car Payment      A     5    G5
8      1000013  16/2/2020    Car Payment      A     1    G5
9      1000015  17/2/2020    Car Payment      A     1    G5
10     1000002   1/1/2020   Rent Payment      B   -47    G6
11     1000004   4/1/2020    Con Payment      B     3    G7
12     1000006   6/1/2020    Con Payment      B     2    G7
13     1000009   9/2/2020  Water payment      B    34    G8
14     1000014  17/2/2020   Test Payment      B     8    G9
15     1000016  19/2/2020   Test Payment      B     2    G9
```

---

#### `factorize`

```
f = lambda x: x.diff().fillna(0).gt(2).cumsum()
d = df.groupby(['Text', 'Vendor']).Days.transform(f)
g = pd.factorize([*zip(df.Text, df.Vendor, d)])[0]
df.assign(Group=[f'G{i + 1}' for i in g])

    Invoice No       Date           Text Vendor  Days Group
0      1000001   1/1/2020   Rent Payment      A     0    G1
1      1000003   2/1/2020   Rent Payment      A     1    G1
2      1000005   4/1/2020   Rent Payment      A     2    G1
3      1000007   6/1/2020  Water payment      A     2    G2
4      1000008   9/2/2020    Rep Payment      A    34    G3
5      1000010   9/2/2020    Car Payment      A     0    G4
6      1000011  10/2/2020    Car Payment      A     1    G4
7      1000012  15/2/2020    Car Payment      A     5    G5
8      1000013  16/2/2020    Car Payment      A     1    G5
9      1000015  17/2/2020    Car Payment      A     1    G5
10     1000002   1/1/2020   Rent Payment      B   -47    G6
11     1000004   4/1/2020    Con Payment      B     3    G7
12     1000006   6/1/2020    Con Payment      B     2    G7
13     1000009   9/2/2020  Water payment      B    34    G8
14     1000014  17/2/2020   Test Payment      B     8    G9
15     1000016  19/2/2020   Test Payment      B     2    G9
```

---

#### Some Details

```
#        The first element of group    Cumulatively summing True/False
#        will get NaN so we fill it    will create a new value every time
#        in with 0         ║           we see a True.  This creates groups
#                          ║               ║     
#         adjacent differences   Should be obvious
#               ╭─┴──╮ ╭───╨───╮ ╭─┴─╮ ╭───╨──╮
f = lambda x: x.diff().fillna(0).gt(2).cumsum()
```

Comment: @piSquared, there small mistake in the input and outputed expected  I had provided, just corrected it.

Comment: what I meant was the requirement is to check the vendor and description and the days column and if the vendor and description are the same and the day difference between adjacent rows is <=2 then the rows should be grouped under a unique new group name

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your conditions into `groupby` and use [**`ngroup`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html).

```
df['Group'] = df['Group'] = (df.groupby([df['Description'].ne(df['Description'].shift()).cumsum(), 
                             df['Vendor'].ne(df['Vendor'].shift()).cumsum(), 
                             df['Days']<=2]).ngroup()+1)
                            .astype(str).str.pad(2, 'left','G') 

# same description : df['Description'].ne(df['Description'].shift()).cumsum()
# same vendor : df['Vendor'].ne(df['Vendor'].shift()).cumsum()
# Days<=2 : df['Days']<=2
```

Output:

```
    Invoice No  Date    Description Vendor  Days    Group
0   123456  2020-01-01  Rent Payment    A   0   G1
1   123457  2020-02-01  Rent Payment    A   1   G1
2   123458  2020-04-01  Rent Payment    A   2   G1
3   123459  2020-06-01  Water Payment   A   2   G2
4   123460  2020-09-02  Rent Payment    A   34  G3
5   123461  2020-09-02  Rep Payment     A   0   G4
6   123462  2020-10-02  Rep Payment     A   1   G4
7   123463  2020-11-02  Rep Payment     A   2   G4
8   123464  2020-02-20  Water Payment   A   11  G5
```

Comment: upto row 4 is its aggining correctly, from row 5 its  not coming correctly.

Comment: Why are you treating `Rent Payment` and `Rep Payment` as same `Description` ? @Rahulrajan

Comment: sorry it is typo,what I meant was the requirement is to check the vendor and description and the days column and if the vendor and description are the same and the day difference between adjacent rows is <=2 then the rows should be grouped under a unique new group name.

Comment: That is exactly what it does. @Rahulrajan in your example there seems to be a mistake. `Rent Payment` and `Rep Payment` are in the same group even though there are not same.